# How to auto copy format when I insert new row above? google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

How can we set a setting in which when we try to insert a new row, it should format automatically? I have already spent a couple of hours solving this problem and went through different sites, but I am still unable to achieve the expectation.

I have tried using `CTRL+D` but it doesn't work as expected.

---

Short Demo (it does not format automatically, when I insert new row above)
[play demo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PzWoPEzSayEWM-RufSqcr9Ff-_DXHoBC/view?usp=sharing)

Spreadsheet link (sheet is readonly, but you may duplicate) [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P35U0hkbKw5sJtLvzmCdS6XYg92WYmiQqP99S9EZKfM/edit?usp=sharing)

---

Expectation is if I insert new row and provide the date of birth, the age column should be automatically calculated and filled.

Comment: either copy-paste it or use script

Comment: Are you open to use Apps Script?

Comment: Your goal is not clear. Are you trying to copy *formatting* (i.e., that cell's background color, font, font-size, etc.)? Or are you trying to get the *formula* to be copied into the row above when you Insert Row(s) Above?

Comment: @ErikTyler thanks for the reply sir. The question is not about the styles, please read the expectation below.

Comment: @GiselleValladares yes I'm open.

Comment: The word "format" (used in your title and post) refers only to what you are calling "style" elements, hence the confusion. While it's possible to construct formulas that will do what you are wanting to do, that goes beyond what a free, volunteer-run forum is designed to provide. That kind of complex, customized work (at least for me) constitutes a client project, not the kind of tweak this site is designed to offer.

Comment: @schutte, I added a sample code you can use as a base.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to copy is just the formula in the `E6` cell every time a new `Date of Birth` is added. You can test this sample code:

*Note: You can change it as necesary*

```
function format() {

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  //this calls a 2D array. 
  const range = sheet.getRange("B6:E").getValues();

  // the formula that will be added in column E
  // the '?' in 'D?' will be replaced with the correct cell number later on. 
  let formula = '=INT((TODAY()-D?)/365)';

  //start the loop for each row
  for (let i = 0; i < range.length ; i++){
    let row = range[i];

    // the if statement will help remove all the empty values in the array
    if(row[2] !== ''){
     
      // replace('?',i+6) will change the value of D? to D6, D7, D8 and so on
      sheet.getRange(i+6,5).setValue(formula.replace('?',i+6));
    };
  };
}
```

After that you can add a [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) when the sheet is edit. Like this:

[image]

It will look something like this:

[image]

Comment: thanks for the effort. let me study about this one first.

Comment: @schutte, You are welcome. If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon). By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. how to accept answer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)